# Shooting Star, assuming an event had occured what would be the probability ...

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, poisson-distribution

Hello I am trying to calculate this question,

Every year there is 5 shooting stars.

I am calculating the stars shooting past in the sky and in the first 6 months i have calculated the probability that there will be at least 2 shooting stars.

```
=2.5 since 5/2 (half a year) 
(≥2)=1−(<2)
```

Now i want to calculate for when there has been at least 4 shooting starts in the first 9 months
assuming that the event above (the shooting star in the first 6 month) had occurred

How should i go about this ...

Comment: would this be dependent or independent if anyone has a advice please let me know

Comment: Clearly the number of shooting stars in the first $9$ months is dependent on the number in the first $6$ months.  If there are $5$ in the first $6$ months the probability that there are $4$ in the first $9$ months is $0$.

Comment: how should i go about finding P(A and B)?

Comment: how should i go about finding P(A and B)

Answer (score 0):

Let $X_{[a,b]}$ denote the number of shooting stars in time interval $[a,b]$ (in months).

It has Poisson distribution with parameter $\frac{5(b-a)}{12}$ and if $[a,b]$ and $[c,d]$ are disjoint then $X_{[a,b]}$ and $X_{[c,d]}$ are independent.

First calculate:$$P(X_{[0,9]}\geq4,X_{[0,6]}\geq2)=$$$$P(X_{[0,9]}\geq 4,X_{[0,6]}=2)+P(X_{[0,9]}\geq4,X_{[0,6]}=3)+P(X_6\geq4)=$$$$P(X_{[0,9]}\geq4\mid X_{[0,6]}=2)P(X_{[0,6]}=2)+P(X_{[0,9]}\geq4\mid X_{[0,6]}=3)P(X_{[0,6]}=3)+P(X_{[0,6]}\geq4)=$$$$P(X_{(6,9]}\geq2)P(X_{[0,6]}=2)+P(X_{(6,9]}\geq1)P(X_{[0,6]}=3)+P(X_{[0,6]}\geq4)$$

In the last equality it is used that $X_{[0,9]}=X_{[0,6]}+X_{[(6,9]}$ and that $X_{[0,6]}$ and $X_{[(6,9]}$ are independent.

Then calculate:$$P(X_{[0,9]}\geq4\mid X_{[0,6]}\geq2)=\frac{P(X_{[0,9]}\geq4,X_{[0,6]}\geq2)}{P(X_{[0,6]}\geq2)}$$